# Mutiple Axios return not able to return the value but in cosole it is coming

Tags: javascript, angular, async-await, axios

Multiple Axios return not able to return the value but in console it is coming
first function is able to return the data>
second and 3rd is not able to do>

< the first function is able to return the data>
<the second and 3rd is not able to do>

```
async getdata() {
  let url = `xxxxxxxx`;
  this.axiosConfig = {
    withCredentials: false,
    maxRedirects: 3
  };
  let config: AxiosRequestConfig = { ...this.axiosConfig
  };
  //axios.defaults.headers.common = { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token }
  var result = await axios.get(url, config);
  console.log(result.data); // --------------> data is coming here
  return result.data; //------------>able to return the data from here
}
async getfame() {
  var res = await this.getdata()
  res.map(async(item: any) => {
    let url = `xxxxxxxx`;
    this.axiosConfig = {
      withCredentials: false,
      maxRedirects: 3
    };
    let config: AxiosRequestConfig = { ...this.axiosConfig
    };
    //axios.defaults.headers.common = { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token }
    var result1 = await axios.get(url, config);
    console.log(result1.data); // -----------------> data coming here
    return result1.data; //------------> not able to return the data from here
    //return axios.get<string>(url, config);
  })
}
async getfix() {
  var res1 = await this.getdata()
  res1.map(async(item: any) => {
    let url = `xxxxxxxx`;
    this.axiosConfig = {
      withCredentials: false,
      maxRedirects: 3
    };
    let config: AxiosRequestConfig = { ...this.axiosConfig
    };
    //axios.defaults.headers.common = { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token }
    var result2 = await axios.get(url, config);
    console.log(result2.data); // -----------------> data coming here
    return result2.data; //------------> not able to return the data from here
    //return axios.get<string>(url, config);   //-------------> tried this way but still not coming
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second and third functions, you're returning those axios calls inside an array map. The outer function is not returning anything.

If you add a return before each `.map()` call, then the functions will return an array of your expected results.

```
async getfame() {
  var res = await this.getdata()
  return res.map(async(item: any) => {
    /* ... */
    return result1.data; 
  })
}
async getfix() {
  var res1 = await this.getdata()
  return res1.map(async(item: any) => {
    /* ... */
    return result2.data;
  })
}
```

Comment: thx it is returning the data in promise.can you let me know how to get the data by aysc wait so tht it should return data not promise

Comment: Async/await is syntax sugar to make a promise read like synchronous code inside a function. It does not convert a promised value to a synchronous value. If you have an async function that returns a value, that response will always be a promise.

Comment: I recommend researching the core fundamentals of promises before relying too much on async/await. Even if you've done that before, it's always a good idea to refresh yourself on fundamentals.